# raw or escape on include in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to escape a file, which I'm including

following code won't escape the html tags in file "_custom_plugin_script.html.twig". Is there another way?

```
<pre>
    {% autoescape true %}
        {% include "_custom_plugin_script.html.twig" | raw %}
    {% endautoescape %}
</pre>
```

After a couple days, I have found a workaround, but not an answer. So first raw would not escape therefore I should use escape. However raw and escape won't work within {% %} but in {{}}.

So here comes the workaround

Content of the Action

```
$customPluginScript = $app['twig']->render('_custom_plugin_script.html.twig', array(
    'data' => $data,
));


return $app['twig']->render('confirm.html.twig', array(
    'data' => $data,
    'customPluginScript' => $customPluginScript
));
```

And the a part of confirm.html.twig

```
<script>
// don't escape content of customPluginScript
  {{ customPluginScript | raw }}
</script>


<!-- escape content of customPluginScript -->
<pre>
  {{ customPluginScript }}
</pre>
```

Comment: [`{{ var|raw }}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) was what I was looking for when I found this question via Google.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
{% filter escape %}
    {% include '...' %}
{% endfilter %}
```

See the docs for [details](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html).

Comment: That might be correct. The docs were updated since then. I'm glad my solution worked and I don't have to work with Symfony2 anymore. Thank you. Maybe somebody else can try. I'll forward it to the team and they might refactor it.

Comment: By the time I asked the question this wasn't working, but it's better to accept for others looking for answers.

Comment: This works great for outputting HTML as entities (e.g. for copy and paste widget examples).

Comment: `filter` has been changed to `apply` for Twig 3.x: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/apply.html

Answer (score 2):

As this is the first result that comes up when googling for `twig include raw` it's worth mentioning that twig now supports this with the following syntax

```
{{ source('AcmeSomeBundle:Default:_custom_plugin_script.html.twig') }}
```

However, this does not render the template as mentioned by barius.

Comment: `The source function returns the content of a template without rendering it` - as I understand, this does not render twig. `|raw` is not for rendering or not rendering twig, it's about output escaping.